# What packages on Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 are need?

Tags: 12.04, apt, dpkg

After I had some troubles with apt-get I added too much packages with the ubuntu-desktop package. Unfortunately, this happened on a ubuntu-server, so there are many unused packages now. Because I'm still a noob in ubuntu, I got a question:

**What packages on Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 are need for a proper running server?**

Thx for answers, if someone is interessted here's the list of my packages (output of `dpkg --get-selections`): http://pastebin.com/c8BA0YRp

Thx for answers and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: As a new user, IMO, it is much much easier to perform a fresh install and install only the packages you need then it is to start removing ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: OK thx, I'll backup my data and try a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you want to remove all non-default packages.

First of all, the desktop version of Ubuntu has a manifest file listing all the packages contained on the cdrom ([example](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.manifest)). Unfortunately it seems that this manifest is not available online for server editions, but you can try to search it on the cdrom.

Also, if you installed `ubuntu-desktop` through `apt-get` you should inspect the log located in  `/var/log/apt/history.log`. This log has entries like this (an example from my machine):

```
Start-Date: 2013-02-18  23:55:18
Commandline: apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
Install: compiz-plugins-main:amd64 (0.9.7.0~bzr19-0ubuntu10, automatic), compizconfig-settings-manager:amd64 (0.9.5.92-0ubuntu3), compiz-plugins:amd64 (0.9.7.12-0ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2013-02-18  23:55:35
```

So you can try to locate the command you issued to install `ubuntu-desktop` and get the listing of the installed packages.

If you opt to do a clean install, before try `tasksel`. It will probably **damage** your system because it doesn't deal well with dependencies, but you have nothing to loose :)

There you can <strike>select "Basic Ubuntu Server" and</strike> deselect "Ubuntu Desktop".

Good luck!

Comment: OK thx, but will `tasksel` delete any data, or will it just install additional software?

Comment: `tasksel` should only install/remove software. In this case it should uninstall all ubuntu-desktop packages. The problem is that it does not deal well with dependencies, so instead of removing only ubuntu-desktop it can damage your system. As said, use it only as a last resort and backup important data.

Comment: In tasksel, "Ubuntu Desktop" isn't selected, so I'll simply do a reinstall, but thx for your help.